# Mist, transaction "couldn't be successfully executed"

Tags: transactions, mist, wallets

For some reason I can't send transactions from my Mist wallet. I'm running the newest version (0.8.7).

When I send a transaction, after a couple of minutes I get the message that the transaction "couldn't be successfully executed". It never gets any confirmations.

I tried it once with the lowest possible fee, once with the standard fee and once with the maximum fee, but all failed after a couple of minutes.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? Is it `The contract won't allow this transaction to be executed`?

Comment: The exact error is: "the transaction from account X to Y couldn't be successfully executed" This message pops up after several minutes in the right lower corner in a yellow box. The strange thing is that all transactions were executed after some amount of time (from 2 hours (original post) to several minutes (transaction today). It might be worth noticing that all transactions were to a Poloniex account

Answer (score 0):

Update your system time to sync with an internet time server

In Windows:
1)Double click on the date&time displayed on the taskbar on the lower right hand corner of your screen
2)Click "Change Date and Time Settings"
3)Click on "Internet Time" tab
4)Check the box "Synchronize with an internet time server"
5)Chose a server (e.g. time.nist.gov) from the drop-down 
6)Click "Update now" button
7)Re-launch Mist and let it finish syncing your node with the block-chain data from its peers before trying to send your transaction again

OS X:
sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com

Linux see:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79112/how-do-i-set-time-and-date-from-the-internet

I had the same issue, so I tried Parity, which threw an error: "Your clock is not in sync. Detected difference is too big for the protocol to work: -2254ms. Synchronize your clock."

When I did the above, I was able to re-launch Mist, Parity, and the Ethereum Wallet client and my transactions could go through with any of those (after finishing syncing the node with the block-chain data from network peers)