# Can't Send ETH out of my Mist ETH wallet

Tags: transactions, mist, ether, wallets

I tried to send some ETHs to another account (i tried different crypto based exchanges) from MIST Wallet but with no success. The amount of ETH in my wallet remains the same and no ETH show up in the exchanges' accounts.

I tried several times, and each transaction in MIST wallet is displayed as "sent" and has "0 of 12 confirmations". My MIST wallet has not completed full synchronisation yet.

Will the transactions happen only when MIST wallet is fully synchronised? If not, how I can get ETH out from the wallet.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use MyEtherWallet if you have the your private key.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the transactions can only be processed once geth is fully synchronised.

You may also have a problem with your system time being off by too much compared to the accepted network time.

See the answer here for details:

[Mist, transaction "couldn't be successfully executed"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9848/mist-transaction-couldnt-be-successfully-executed/29409#29409)